# Configuration for log driver logfile

Tags: nightwatch.js

I've implemented nightwatchjs in my project and the start is there. However, something I don't like is that the chrome and gecko driver are placing a log file in my root directory. I'ld much prefer this to move to a logging location.

```
    disable_error_log: true,
    desiredCapabilities: {
        silent: true,
        browserName: 'firefox',
        alwaysMatch: {
            acceptInsecureCerts: true,
            'moz:firefoxOptions': {
                args: []
            }
        }
    },
    webdriver: {
        start_process: true,
        server_path: GeckoDriver.path,
        cli_args: []
    }
},
chrome: {
    disable_error_log: true,
    desiredCapabilities: {
        silent: true,
        browserName: 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
            args: []
        }
    },
    webdriver: {
        log_path: false,
        start_process: true,
        server_path: ChromeDriver.path,
        cli_args: [
        ]
    }
}
```

Right now the configuration is as above. Two questions here for the logging are:

1. wat setting do you use to turn it on or off
2. what setting do you use to change the location and or file name for the log

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Nightwatch on a Mac machine and in my `nightwatch.conf.js` file I have a Selenium object that has a `log_path` property.  The path currently is `logs/` but I just tried to remove the path and put `false` as the path and that worked for me.  If you want to turn it off, put `false` as the path for `log_path`, otherwise put the name of the directory (mine is `logs/`).  As far as changing the name of the `selenium-server.log` file, I do not think you can change this, unless someone has create an `npm` module that gives the ability to extend Nightwatch.

```
selenium: {
        "start_process": true,
        "server_path": "bin/selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar",
        "log_path": false,
        "port": 4444,
        "cli_args": {
            "webdriver.chrome.driver": this.chromePath
        }
    }
```

[link for nightwatch docs](https://nightwatchjs.org/gettingstarted/configuration/#selenium-server-settings)

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same issue. I solve this by setting value of log_path in webdriver object of each driver.

you can make changes as like:

```
chrome: {
   disable_error_log: true,
   desiredCapabilities: {
       silent: true,
       browserName: 'chrome',
       chromeOptions: {
           args: []
       }
   },
   webdriver: {
       start_process: true,
       server_path: ChromeDriver.path,
       log_path:'log_folder',     // add this line to your every webdriver object.
       cli_args: [
       ]
   }
}
```

You can off your driverLog generation by setting log_path to false. If you want to specify some specific folder to store the driverLog file then you have to set the log_path to desired location.